# Is it possible so that when we input the authors name it get automatically linked to profile page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Currently am working on a bookstore application. http://framzndesinz.com/demo/bookstore/index.php/books/responsivedesign Author(s): suzuki Takahashi, Ibrahim sejen I want sepearte hyperlink for the 2 authors show. It will be going to their respective author pages when click. The author page will be having a description about author,authors image gallery and list of books written by him. Please Help. Can anyone tell how can it be done.

Is it possible so that when we input the authors name it get automatically linked to profile page?

Comment: We need to see some code, it's almost impossible for us to guess what you need doing. In the simplest form, yes it is possible. Provide code examples.

Comment: This is the link of the page for which am working.http://framzndesinz.com/demo/bookstore/index.php/books/responsivedesign Itz done using Pyrocms.I have used the pages module of pyrocms

Comment: Do authors have profiles already?

Comment: Yes there will be a separate page for authors  also

Comment: have you tried anything till now, a descriptive question like this is hard to give the exact solution. table structure will give us some idea though

Comment: am using the table structure of pyrocms

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_pages_bookslisting`(`id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`created` datetime NOT NULL,`updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,`created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`ordering_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`bookname` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`genre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`book_poster` char(15)COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`release_date` int(11)DEFAULT NULL,`book_details`longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,`language`text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,`authors`varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))

Comment: I want to link the authors name to the author profile page

Comment: This is the author profile page table structure
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_pages_authors` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordering_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `celb_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `celb_photo` char(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `celb_profile` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)